# How to render special characters in jinja templates with flask

Tags: python, json, flask, rss, jinja2

I am fetching data from an API as JSON in Flask, and attempting to render this out to a Jinja Template as RSS, but characters from the JSON such as apostrophes and emdashes get rendered out as `â€™` and `â€”` in the template.

How do I ensure the template renders the proper characters?

This is my code in flask:

```py
json_resp = resp.json()
posts = json_resp['list']
template = render_template('recs.rss',posts=posts)
response = make_response(template)
response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml')
return response
```

and this is the recs.rss template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      ...
      {% for post in posts %}
      <item>
        {% if post.title %}<title><![CDATA[{{ post.title }}]]></title>{% endif %}
        ...
      </item>
      {% endfor %}
   </channel>
</rss>
```

If I encode it as utf-8:

`post_item['title'] = post_item['title'].encode('utf-8'`

I get utf-8 encoding in the RSS feed, and it seems to be prefaced with a `b` instead of a `u`:

```
b'The Dirty Secret of \xe2\x80\x98Secret Family Recipes\xe2\x80\x99'
```

If I attempt to then decode using utf-8 as suggested in the comment below and this post:

[Python Selenium ().text returns "â€™" instead of apostrophe (')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737316/python-selenium-text-returns-%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-instead-of-apostrophe)

I get an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 20: invalid start byte
```

I'm wondering if there is some way to fix this with headers that I send to the jinja template, or something that can be placed within the Jinja template itself to allow for the existance of things like curly quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Selenium ().text returns "â€™" instead of apostrophe (')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737316/python-selenium-text-returns-%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-instead-of-apostrophe)

Comment: @MichaelRuth - not really. I know that there is some issue with encoding here - I added more clarification to the question.

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting encoding for the XML with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`? Did you try setting charset in the Content-Type header with `application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8`?

Comment: @KarlSutt - the content-type header was the missing piece! (I had the encoding in the xml tag but it wasn't working). Feel free to write this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Good stuff — glad you got it working! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the response body encoding in the `Content-Type` header with `application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8`.