# Convert non-ascii character to ascii character

Tags: python

I'm looking for convert this string :

```
test = "Il Ã©tait toujours temps dâ€™Ã©touffer lâ€™inflation par la hausse des taux"
```

to this:

```
test = "Il était toujours temps d'étouffer l'inflation par la hausse des taux"
```

I mean replace the non ascii character by "real" words/letters.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-make-the-python-interpreter-correctly-handle-non-ascii-characters-in-stri).

Comment: I see the topic but I don't want to remove non ascii, just to convert to real letter.
I put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in the top of my file but it's do not work instead.

Comment: I see, then you can consider [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
```

I've tried this and it works. I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737316/python-selenium-text-returns-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-instead-of-apostrophe)

Comment: Note that this applies because the text is in fact the result of incorrectly interpreting UTF-8 bytes as cp1252. If they'd been some other form of bytes, or interpreted as some other erroneous encoding, you need to change the precise arguments involved.